# Can't Connect to Mac After Upgrading Visual Studio to 17.4.0 Preview 1.0

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

I've been connecting to my MacBook Air for about three months now to do development with MAUI.  I just upgraded Visual Studio 2022 from 17.3.0 Preview 3.0 to 17.4.0 Preview 1.0.  Now the Connect to Mac is broken - the same connection I've been using.

The error message is "The Xcode license status couldn't be verified because Xcode has not been found on the default location of the connected Mac.  Having Xcode installed and functional is necessary in order to build and run iOS apps, so please check that Xcode is installed and that the path specified under iOS Settings is correct."

Of course Xcode is installed because it's been working for some time.  I found older posts that reported the same problem and have tried the fixes they suggested but to no avail.  When I plug in a value in the Xcode Path in the VS settings, it doesn't save it.  I can't find a way to go back to 17.3.0 Preview 3.0, so now that it's broken does anyone know how to fix it?

**UPDATES**

As I've continued to work on this problem, I've found this.  First, if I close VS and reopen - **WITHOUT OPENING MY PROJECT** - and go into the Tools...Options...Xamarin...iOS Settings, I can a) put a path in the Xcode path property and then b) click on the Pair to Mac button and have it connect successfully (or so it says).  So the settings look like this:

[image]

Then after I've connected it, it shows that I've paired to a Mac, as shown here:

[image]

Note that if I open my project when I start VS, it automatically tries to connect to the Mac and fails with the error above.  But in this case, it shows it's connected to my Mac.  So I open my project, and on the Debugger menu go to select a simulator from the iOS Simulators.  But instead of showing all of the emulators available with Xcode on the Mac, it just says "Simulator", as shown here:

[image]

Now if I try and start debugging the application, it churns for a few seconds, and then stops with a message that says "An active connection to the Mac is required in order to launch the application. Please ensure the connection is established and try again".  It then shows that I no longer have a connection to my Mac, as you see here:

[image]

If I select my Mac and click the Connect button again, then I get the same error message that I've described above, as shown here:

[image]

When I click on the OK button, it gives me another error message that says "The Xcode tools validation couldn't be performed because IDB has not been started successfully on the paired Mac, which is necessary in order to read the iOS Remote Settings. Having a non functional paired Mac or the Xcode tools not updated could cause unwanted behaviors. Please check the logs to see what happened with IDB initialization on the paired Mac."  This is the dialog:

[image]

At this point, if I click the OK button again, I get yet a different message that says "The connection to the Mac has been lost in the middle of the process. Please try to connect again", as shown here:

[image]

Trying to connect from that point forward will fail every time with the error message previously described, "The Xcode license status couldn't be verified because Xcode has not been found on the default location of the connected Mac. Having Xcode installed and functional is necessary in order to build and run iOS apps, so please check that Xcode is correctly installed and that the path specified under iOS Settings is correct."  If I close VS and start over again though, then I can repeat all of these steps and outcomes.

Comment: It looks like this version of Visual Studio added a rollback feature to the installer. 
 Try that out.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#1740-pre10--visual-studio-2022-version-174-preview-1

Comment: Aye, crud.  That was a fantastic suggestion, really...but it didn't work.  The rollback says it worked, but I still get the same error when trying to connect to my Mac.  I've about reached my limit with VS and MAUI...

Comment: I am in the process of rolling back from 17.4 Prev1 to 17.3 Prev 6.  I could no longer run my MAUI project.  Could not run in Windows or select any Android emulator.

Comment: What is your Xcode version and have you set the command line tools correctly in Xcode?

Comment: The version is 13.4.1, and I'm not sure what needs to be configured since it's been working fine for the last three months.  But I can take a look if you can tell me what I need to do with the command line tools?

Comment: Another note - when I try and connect to this same Mac from another PC with VS 17.2 Preview 6, it works fine. So clearly Xcode is installed and working correctly on the  Mac.  It's only updating VS that has broken everything.

Comment: In Xcode, Open `Preference`-->`Locations`-->`Command line Tools` to check it is being configured. Besides, I also updated my VS to 17.4 Prev1, it can pair to Mac without issue.

Comment: Oh, besides it worked for you?  That's great, would you mind sending me an RDP file for your machine along with an admin username and password so I can use it?  Oh, not possible?  Yes, then I guess the rest of us have to get it working on our own machines.  For everyone not named Alexandar May, I ended up doing a full uninstall of VS 2022 17.3 and VS 2022 Preview 17.4, then reinstalling 17.3 only and magically the iOS simulator feature started working.

Comment: I have 17.4.1 and it's not working still :(

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem for me.  It was an answer from Microsoft Support when I faced a similar issue with a .net 6.0 preview and solved the problem for me with the same issue in .net 7/VS 17.4.0 GA release:

Remove the `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet` folder on the MacOS build host, then add a `global.json` file to your project/solution folder on your Windows 10 development machine that explicitly specifies the exact SDK version without any roll forward strategy:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.100",
    "allowPrerelease": false,
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

Finally connect to the MacOS build host again using the “Pair to Mac” dialog, which will then install the correct .NET SDK and also successfully install the correct workload on the MacOS build host.

Comment: After attempting a number of workarounds to get my windows PC talking to my mac, including installing VS for Mac Preview, this fixed the connection.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: the only hack that worked for me